# Web map export using custom print template giving ERROR 000800

Tags: arcgis-pro, printing, arcgis-enterprise, error-000800

**ArcGIS Pro**: 3.0.3

**ArcGIS Enterprise Server (Linux)**: 10.9.1

We are trying to implement custom print templates so we can print web maps with our logos, formatted scale bar, etc using the versions above. I followed the following tutorials to create a custom print service so we can utilize additional templates for printing web maps.

https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/tutorial-publish-additional-...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUHg7rgTRn4

However, the export fails every time and we receive the following error.

> Error executing tool. Export Web Map : ERROR 000800: The value is not
> a member of MAP_ONLY.'

[image: snapshot]

As you can see, the Layout_Template parameter contains an array with two values: Layout and MAP_ONLY. However, I don't think the layout options is being recognized. I've published the ExportWebMap service with both MAP_ONLY and Layout as the default value, but haven't had any luck.

Does the PAGX file need to be in a registered data store folder in addition to publishing the Export Web Map tool?

Documentation seems vague on this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ArcGIS Enterprise Server 10.x.x, you must have ArcGIS Pro 2.x.x installed to leverage custom print services. As @PolyGeo mentioned, ArcGIS Pro 3.0.x is intended to be deployed with ArcGIS Enterprise 11.0.x.

**References**

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/error-executing-tool-export-web-map-error-000800/m-p/1242983#M34837

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/custom-print-service-failing/m-p/1190845#M33454